# Add item to nested array in redux-toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit

Redux Toolkit is giving me mutation errors when trying to update state on a nested array, which I thought it was using immer to get around this and simplify the reducers.

My store looks like :

state -> forms -> sections

I want to add a section to an existing form.

My action takes a form and a section

the reducer looks like

```
let intialState={
    forms:[]
}

const FormsReducer = createReducer(intialState, {
    ADD_SECTION: (state, action) => {
        const index = state.forms.findIndex(f => f.id === action.form.id);
        state.forms[index].__formSections.push(action.payload);
        },
```

> A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `FormsReducer.forms.0.__formSections.0`

Yet according to the redux-toolkit documentation is should be possible to "write "mutative" immutable update logic"...

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: have u figured it out by any chance?

Comment: Is this still happening for you?  I know this is an old question so maybe it's a bug that was fixed.  I am not able to reproduce it: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-add-form-data-d91qw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns/#nested-data-structures

Answer (score 0):

If you return it without mutating from reducer the error will not occur

```js
const FormsReducer = createReducer(intialState, {
    ADD_SECTION: (state, action) => {
        const newstate = {...state}
        const index = newstate.forms.findIndex(f => f.id === action.form.id);
        newstate.forms[index].__formSections.push(action.payload);
        return newstate 
},
```